# Why does the trash compactor move so slow?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

I'm assuming the out of universe answer is for a plot device so you can have the dramatic will they be saved etc...

But what is the in universe reason?

Comment: Maybe wanted to give time for the trash monster to reach a safe spot.  The Empire might be evil, but squishing animals, that's a whole different level of evil.

Comment: Probably the same reason hydraulic car compactors in real life aren't that fast: Crushing power is a much higher priority than speed.

Comment: +1 @ixrec.  Particularly when crushing lots of metal beams and such (as we see in the trash compactor, and as exist in cars being crushed IRL) it's helpful to crush slowly.  Going fast creates a loud impact, but the metal resists and rebounds, requiring even more force applied to keep going.  On the other hand, slow moving but irresistable force will allow the metal structures time to bend and collapse under the pressure.  The result is a much more efficient compaction of material for less overall energy input, but it does take more time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The same reason real-world trash compactors do

Here’s the trash compactor scene:

We can see that Luke, Leia, and Han are struggling in the trash compactor for about forty or fifty seconds after the walls start moving.

Compare that to this smaller real-world trash compactor:

It takes about thirty seconds to compact some ordinary Earth garbage. This isn’t so different from the time the trash compactor in the film took.

Why do *actual* trash compactors move so slowly, then? As [suggested](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/74057/steve-o) in the comments, it can be more efficient to compress metal and other such materials slowly, allowing their bonds to deform rather than reacting inelastically. Presumably space trash compactors act on similar principles.